# Pytorch Deep Learning - Class Model() and training function

Tags: python, oop, pytorch

I am new to Pytorch and I am going through this tutorial to figure out how to do deep learning with this library. I have problem figuring out part of the code.

There is a class called Net and an object called model instantiated from it. Then there is the training function called  train(epoch). In the next line in the train function body I see this: model.train() which I can't make any sense of. Would you please help me in understanding this part of the code? how we are calling a method of a class when this method has not been defined inside the class? and how come the method has the exact same name as function it has been called inside?    This is the class definition:

```
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 32, kernel_size=3)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size=3)
        self.conv2_drop = nn.Dropout2d()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(2304, 256)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(256, 17)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(F.max_pool2d(self.conv1(x), 2))
        x = F.relu(F.max_pool2d(self.conv2_drop(self.conv2(x)), 2))
        x = x.view(x.size(0), -1) # Flatten layer
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.dropout(x, training=self.training)
        x = self.fc2(x)
        return F.sigmoid(x)

model = Net() # On CPU
# model = Net().cuda() # On GPU
```

And this is the function defined after this class:

```
def train(epoch):
    model.train()
    for batch_idx, (data, target) in enumerate(train_loader):
        # data, target = data.cuda(async=True), target.cuda(async=True) # On GPU
        data, target = Variable(data), Variable(target)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        output = model(data)
        loss = F.binary_cross_entropy(output, target)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        if batch_idx % 10 == 0:
            print('Train Epoch: {} [{}/{} ({:.0f}%)]\tLoss: {:.6f}'.format(
                epoch, batch_idx * len(data), len(train_loader.dataset),
                100. * batch_idx / len(train_loader), loss.data[0]))
```

Comment: I'm also new to PyTorch.. but as much I understand is that you have created your Net Class with nn.Module and now your object "model" of type Net can use methods like train(),eval() which are of nn.Module.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Now, my question is: why do we have to set the model in the training mode? we are defining a model ourselves and then defining a train function too. Why model.train()?

Comment: Just because you're using Supervised learning. Creating a model is one step, training is another and evaluating is next. that's how supervised learning works.
check: https://machinelearningmastery.com/start-here/#process

Answer (score 2):

#### train vs model.train

The `def train(epochs): ...` is the method to train the model and is not an attribute of `Net` class. `model` is an object of `Net` class, that inherits from `nn.Module`.
In PyTorch, all layers inherit from `nn.Module` and that gives them a lot of common functionality like `model.children()` or `layer.children()`, `model.apply()`, etc.
The `model.train()` is similarly implemented in `nn.Module`. It doesn't actually train the model or any layer that inherits from `nn.Module` but sets it in train mode, so say it's equivalent to doing `model.set_train()`.
There is an equivalent method `model.eval()` you would call in to set the evaluation mode before testing the model.

#### Why do you even need it?

There can be some parameters in a layer/model that are suppose to act differently while training and evaluation modes. The obvious example are `BatchNorm`'s γ and β